# How do I implement text forms(?) using django or HTML

Tags: django

First sorry for my bad english and my unclear question.

I am trying to make my own blog that can post articles.

Using django basic form is convenient, but its form is just plain.

I want to be able to underline, change colors, and use images.

So basically I want to the feature the image below

[the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9XU8.png)

I want to implement the thing in the black oval (I don't know its specific name... T.T).

So is there any APIs or feature implemented in django itself? Or can you tell me what it is called? I don't know what it is called in english so I can't search for it at all..

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Please add the code of what you have done so far.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don’t have specific code for it because I didn’t write any yet. I am trying to find out what I can and can’t do with django.

Comment: What you're looking for is named a wyswyg editor. There are quite a few of them, and there are quite a few django apps integrating them as django widgets, cf https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/wysiwyg/

Comment: Thank you!! That helped me a lot. A wysiwyg editor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by`tinyMCE`, `quilljs`. 
But you should have basic understanding how django form works.

Comment: Thank you! So there is text editer API for people like me!! Thank you for your kind Answer!!

Comment: It this solve then mark it accepted.